# How to write data to a file in the projects directory?

Tags: ios, json, swift, file

I've some irregular huge amount of data in a text file, and by some crucial logics I've made it just like the way I needs. Now on every time the app loads the whole process if could be performed will cost deficiency up to remarkable extent.
So what should I do in order to store this regular data for one permanent time, so then through that I should retrieve when and where I got need of it?
Data is an unmodifiable pure in text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay your question is very vague, but to give you a head start you can save data to a file and then read from it like this:

```
let file = "file.txt" //this is the file we will write to and read from it

let text = "some text" //your data/text

if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

    //writing
    do {
        try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch {
        /* error handling here */
    }

    //reading
    do {
        let textOut = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        //use textOut - your content
    }
    catch {
        /* error handling here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for concern ... It is writing to and reading from a file that if you run on your simulator can't find

Comment: I needs to write to a file that after writing I might be able to see and interact with, just like we do normally with files in our computers.

Comment: If I write the way you told me then where should I find that specific file 'file.txt'. where will it be saved if I run that on an ios simulator.

Comment: It saves it inside the Documents folder of the app (each app on your simulator has a special folder to store files in ). 'NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first' You can then pull the data back out again at any point.